# JQL Query not spitting out correct content JIRA

Tags: jira, jql

I thought his would work well (and the syntax is correct) so maybe someone has an idea of how to do this?

I did alter it so its easier to read (by moving parts to each line).

breaking them up into three separate filters would obviously be the easy solution but i want to look at all three. Does JIRA not support JQL if too convoluted?

```
project = SRFS AND resolution = Unresolved AND 
(
(
"CB Complete?"=No AND "CB"> 0 
AND "CB Due Date">= startOfWeek(-1) AND "CB Due Date"<= endOfWeek(-1)
) 
OR (
"PWD Complete?"=No AND "PWD" > 0 
AND "PWD Due Date">= startOfWeek(-1) AND "PWD Due Date"<= endOfWeek(-1)
) 
OR (
"RTL Complete"=No AND "RTL"> 0 
AND "RTL Due Date">= startOfWeek(-1) AND "RTL Due Date"<= endOfWeek(-1)
)
)
```

Comment: What is the result you would like to see?

Comment: @GlennV I figured it out, The "-1"'s were the issue :)